# how to filter records filtered by more than one criterion in pivot table - laravel eloquent collections

Tags: laravel, filter, eloquent, relationship

I am remodeling a book recommendation personal site. I want to filter books by more than one criterion.

For example, I want to display all books which are BOTH philosophy and science-fiction. Peter Watt's Blindsight being an example of this.

Now I can do only a single criterion filter:

I have a pivot table for

Model Books

```
public function genres()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Genre', 'bookgenres', 'book_id', 'genre_id');
}
```

Model Genre:

```
public function books()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Book', 'bookgenres', 'genre_id', 'book_id');
}
```

The pivot table  **bookgenres** sample:
`id`,`book_id`, `genre_id`

1 - 23 - 4

2 - 23 - 5

3 - 24 - 4

In plain English: The book #23 is both SF (#4) and philosophy (#5), while book #24 is only SF (#4)

With these, I just query

```
$genre = 4;
$books = Genre::find($genre)->books()->get();
```

and use a standard @foreach loop to list books

---

**To do:** filter the collection by two genres, not one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you're going to have to use a join for that. There are pivot querying functions, but I doubt they can be used how you'd like. But if you want to try, it's something like ``Book::wherePivot('genre_id', 'someId')->wherePivot('genre_id', 'someOtherId')->get()``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query relations with [`whereHas`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations)

Here I'm using the name of the genre. If you want you can also use the id. Just change the column name and obviously the array.

```
$genres = array('philosophy', 'science-fiction');
$books = Book::whereHas('genres', function($query) use ($genres){
    $query->whereIn('name', $genres);
})->get();
```

Comment: thank you! that is a great help! can i direct your attention to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27653323/laravel-4-relations-how-display-a-top-5-ranking-of-records-voted-by-users

Comment: You're welcome. I'll take a look at it. Looks like a lot of work though... ;)

Comment: @lukasgeiter I couldn't accept the answer... I didn't ask the question. :p But I did upvote it.

Comment: @nhbjgfcxhgchg Hahaha my bad :P Thought you were the OP... Thanks for the upvote though :)

Comment: @nhbjgfcxhgchg thanks for your suggestion! Maybe you could take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27653700/4209866 
I am now stuck at PROBLEM 4 in my own answer - additional filter by a pivot table