# Eloquent query - COUNT and SUM on multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to use knowledge from this question 
[question already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27653323/laravel-4-relations-how-display-a-top-5-ranking-of-records-voted-by-users/27668075)

In my pivot table 
**user_attitudes** I have two columns:

- importance  (the users are declaring their interest (0,3))
- attitude (basically this one is for upvoting and downvoting, values are '-1', '0' and '1')

### What I have now:

I can print a list of Entity ordered by the value created by **selectRaw**.

### What I need:

I wish to print a different all four values described below, unregardedly which one is used for sorting

I wish to create several sorting switches with AJAX, so that users can change sorting.

For every I need to output up to **four counts**:
Total importance score:

```
SUM(user_attitudes.importance) AS importance
```

To show how many users are observing the Entity:

```
COUNT(user_attitudes.importance) AS observing
```

Total count of upvotes and downvotes:

```
SUM(user_attitudes.attitude) AS karma
```

Number of users who down- or upvoted a iven Entity:

```
COUNT(user_attitudes.importance) AS
```

How I can expand the below query?
Where in this query I can ask for the above extra numbers?

```
$rank_entities = Entity::leftJoin('user_attitudes', function($q){
                $q->on('entity_id', '=', 'entities.id');
                $q->where('item_type', '=', 'entity');
            })
            ->selectRaw('entities.*, SUM(user_attitudes.importance) AS importance')
            ->groupBy('entities.id')
            ->orderBy('importance', 'desc')
            ->take(6)
            ->get();
```

I tried to add another

```
->selectRaw('entities.*, SUM(user_attitudes.attitude) AS karma')
```

but it seems only one selectRaw can create a printable variable
Any ideas? thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add them to the current `selectRaw`? Here I'm using an array to make it a bit cleaner:

```
$selects = array(
    'entities.*',
    'SUM(user_attitudes.importance) AS importance',
    'COUNT(user_attitudes.importance) AS observing',
    'SUM(user_attitudes.attitude) AS karma'
);

// query ...

->selectRaw(implode(',', $selects))
```

Comment: could you help me on this post? `https://stackoverflow.com/q/51226415/1830228` thanks